# Using summarize and userelationship to generate a sum based on a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Story:**

I have two date columns in my fact table, one is for `orderdate` and the second is for `orderdate`/`refund`/`cancelled date`.

I created two relationships between the date table and the fact table.

- Active: Date > OrderDate
- Inactive: Date > OtherDate

I would like to sum the # of refunds per day using the inactive relationship.

**What I tried:**

```
Returns =
VAR summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( Query1, Query1[kind] = "refund" ),
        Query1[orderId],
        "returns", MAX ( Query1[amount] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Query1[amount] ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( Query1[OtherDate], DateTable[Date] ),
        summary
    )
```

For some reason, it's using the active date column. Any suggestion on how to fix the above formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand how you are intending to use the `summary` variable here, but note that `USERELATIONSHIP` doesn't affect it at all since it's already computed.

You might not need that variable at all. Try this:

```
Returns =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Query1[amount] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Query1[OtherDate], DateTable[Date] ),
    Query1[kind] = "refund"
)
```

Comment: when i put it in a table, it works but the total row shows the latest refund instead of summing the entire column, any idea why?

Comment: Yes. It's because you are taking the max, not the sum.

Comment: Makes sense, but now it adds the same refunds twice on certain days... is it possible to keep max (in order to not count duplicates) or change it for sum (but not count the duplicates)

Comment: Try wrapping the whole thing in a sum: `SUMX( VALUES( Query1[orderId] ), [Returns] )`.

Comment: it multiplies the refund amount by the distinct amount of orders

Comment: Instead of `orderId` use whatever level of granularity you are trying to sum over. I have no idea what that is supposed to be.

Comment: Well it should be orderId if the orderId is being duplicated. For example: Order id # 3 can appear three times due to sucess , refund and cancelled values (they are independent transactions). So the granularity is orderId

Comment: Does it help if you use `FILTER ( Query1, Query1[kind] = "refund" )` instead of `Query1[kind] = "refund"`?

Comment: unfortunately no.